# Is it possible to freeze (make immutable) a class or a method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, monkeypatching

In Ruby:

```
module Example
  class ExampleValidator
    def mymethod
      # do something important
    end
  end
end
```

Is it possible to make `mymethod` immutable (i.e. no monkey patching)?

Otherwise it would also be acceptable to "freeze" the entire class `ExampleValidator`.

Comment: Sounds like an XY Problem. Why do you need to freeze the code?

Comment: I'm a Pythonista, but: unless for some reason you want to use the method as a dictionary key, this sounds like a social problem (someone else who works on your codebase is monkeypatching something, and you would prefer that the code not be written that way) than a technical problem. If you *do* want to use it as a dictionary key, then I don't think monkeypatching actually matters - the actual *method object* isn't being mutated, it's just being replaced.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can call [`freeze`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Module.html#method-i-freeze) on a Module.

```
Example::ExampleVaildator.freeze
```

However, [I'd question why this is necessary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Perhaps it is solving a social problem with a technical one. A tool such as [Rubocop](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/1.25/cops_lint.html#lintduplicatemethods) should warn about monkey patches.